# Extract original object from matplotlib legend entry for errorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I create a simple plot like this with the `errorbar` function and add legend text at the end

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p1 = plt.errorbar([1,2],[3,4])
p2 = plt.errorbar([1,2],[5,6])

leg = plt.legend(('a','b'))
```

is there any way I can still programmatically identify which legend entry belongs to which plot? Because `keys = [h.get_label() for h in leg.legendHandles]` only returns `_nolegend_` for both while `p1.get_label()` is still `None`. Is there any other way to link the actual legend text to its plot?

**EDIT**
Maybe to make my intentions more clear: I am aware that providing a label directly during the plot command helps. But I am working on a package where a I would like to check whether a certain object is represented in any form in the legend. So far, it seems like this can't be said for certain based only on the `Artist` object and the legend handle without knowledge of the plot order, right?

Answer (score 1):

Defining the axis beforehand helps, at least in my solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
p1 = ax.errorbar([1,2],[3,4], label='a')
p2 = ax.errorbar([1,2],[5,6], label='b')
plt.legend()

leg = ax.get_legend()
print([x.get_text() for x in leg.texts])
```

Comment: Yes, if you set the labels inside the `errorbar` command, they are attached directly to the `ErrorbarContainer`. However, this eventually only changes the legend text, the `label` of the legend handles remains `_nolegend_`. So, if the legend text is changed again via `plt.legend`, the connection is fully lost.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.legend(('a','b'))` means to make a legend for each artist in an axes children list, which can be obtained by `Axes.get_children()`. So you can iterate over the legend text list together with the axes's children artist, and if a children artist matches the plotted `p1` or `p2`, then you can link the legend text to the corresponding plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p1 = plt.errorbar([1,2],[3,4])
p2 = plt.errorbar([1,2],[5,6])

leg = plt.legend(('a','b'))

children = plt.gca().get_children()

mapping = {}
artists = [p1, p2]
for txt, art in zip(leg.get_texts(), children):
    for p in artists:
        if p.lines[0] is art:
            mapping[p] = txt.get_text()
            artists.remove(p)
```

Then `mapping[p1]` will be `'a'`, and `mapping[p2]` will be `'b'`.

However, as the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html?highlight=legend#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) suggests, the call signature of `legend(labels)` is discouraged, because the relation between plot elements and labels is only implicit by their order and can easily be mixed up.

The recommended way to add a legend is such as @Giovanni Tardini did, and that way will make your link more easily. After all, *Explicit is better than implicit.*, as the **The Zen of Python** said.

Comment: Thanks. I probably formulated my question a bit misleading. I know providing a label is the recommended approach. My goal is to find something robust that even works when the labels are set via `legend(labels)`. However, if this is officially discouraged, it might be ok to not cover this edge case then.